# calculate maximum sum if same number is picked from continuous segment

Tags: dynamic-programming

calculate maximum sum if same number is picked from continuous segment

```
[1,2,3,4] => answer 6
if 1 is picked from continuous segment [1,1,1,1] then sum is 4 
if 2 is picked from continuous segment [2,3,4] then sum is 6 , 

[6,0,6,5,5,2] => answer 15, continuous segment [6,5,5] , 
5 can be picked from 3 elements.
[1,100,1,1] => answer 100, we can't pick 1 as 1+1+1+1 = 4 <100
```

I can't think any solution except O(n^2) loop

Comment: We need to pick sum of common elements from a positive integer arrary.

Comment: What's with the tag spamming?

Comment: Added code with logging. Hope that helps!

Comment: what are the inputs? Is it just an array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`O(n)` complexity. Use a stack. While numbers are increasing push indexes to stack. If the number is equal or lower or the array ends, pop the indexes of equal or larger numbers from the stack and calculate. Continue.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(arr){
  let stack = [0];
  let best = arr[0];
  
  function collapse(i, val){
    console.log(`Collapsing... i: ${i}; value: ${val}`);
    
    while (stack.length && arr[ stack[stack.length - 1] ] >= val){
      let current_index = stack.pop();
      let left_index = stack.length ? stack[stack.length - 1] : -1;
      console.log(`i: ${i}; popped: ${current_index}; value: ${arr[current_index]}; potential: ${i - left_index - 1} * ${arr[current_index]}`)
      best = Math.max(best, (i - left_index - 1) * arr[current_index]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log('Starting... stack: ' + JSON.stringify(stack));
  
  for (let i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (!stack.length || arr[ stack[stack.length - 1] ] < arr[i]){
      stack.push(i);
      console.log(`Pushing ${i}; stack: ${JSON.stringify(stack)}`);
    
    } else {
      collapse(i, arr[i]);
      stack.push(i);
      console.log(`Pushing ${i}; stack: ${JSON.stringify(stack)}`);
    }
  }
  
  if (stack.length)
    collapse(stack[stack.length - 1] + 1, -Infinity);
  
  return best;
}

//console.log(f([5,5,4]))
//console.log(f([1,2,3,4]))
console.log(f([6,0,6,5,5,2]))
```

Comment: for stack: (1,0), (2,6), while popping (2,6) the current become 2, how do you calculate the index_range is 5 ? what is the formula of index_range ?

Comment: @xyz current would be the value, `6`, not the index (2). By `index_range` I meant the number of elements that would be included in the current count, a calculation derived from the two indexes covering the range in question.

Comment: pop (2,6) => **`best = max(6, 2 * 5) = 10,`**
                    **`best = max(best, current * index_range)`**
current = 2, index_range=5 ,how ?

Comment: @xyz current = 5, index_range = 2 :) There are two elements in that calculation.

Answer (score 3):

[@גלעד ברקן](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630905/8629960)'s answer is right and should be accepted. However I decided to implement the stack solution for the sake of interest and to help @xyz sort it out.

```js
let a = [5,5,4,4,6];

console.log(`Answer: ${traverse(a)}`);

function traverse(a) {
    let i, max = 0, stack = [0];
    for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= a[stack[stack.length - 1]]) {
            stack.push(i);
        } else {
            pop(i);
            stack.push(i);
        }
    }
    if (stack.length) pop(i, true);
    function pop(index, end) {
        while (stack.length && (a[stack[stack.length - 1]] >= a[index] || end)) {
            let p = stack.pop();
            let range = stack.length ? index - stack[stack.length - 1] - 1 : index;
            max = Math.max(max, range * a[p]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: This is giving wrong answer for [5,5,4] => ideally answer should be 4+4+4 =  12, but the answer from the algo is 10.

Comment: Finally I found some time to sort this out